# Unwanted whitespaces and wrong encoding with fwrite

Tags: php

I'm doing a simple `**fwrite**` in a **csv file** writing one line afte the other:

```
//Clean maybe empty entries of last winners
    $cleaned = array();
    $tick = 0;
    $debug = "";
    if (($fh = fopen(LAST_WINNERS_PATH, 'r+b')) !== FALSE) {
        if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 300, ';')) !== FALSE) {
                $tick++;
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $row[$key] = stripslashes($value);
                }
                if ($row[0] != '') {
                    array_push($cleaned, $row);
                }
            }
            array_reverse($cleaned);
            ftruncate($fh, 0);
            $count = count($cleaned);
            foreach ($cleaned as $key => $row) {
                $string = implode(";", $row);
                if ($key < $count -1) {
                    $string .= PHP_EOL;
                }
                fwrite($fh, $string);
            }
            flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
        } else {
        }
        fclose($fh);
    } else {
    }
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Everything is in **utf-8**, but the **csv file** converts every time back to ANSI, when writing to it. Why and what can be don to prevent this?
2. In front of the first line every time several whitespaces are added. How to avoid that?

Comment: Show us your `fopen` and handler, also, have you considered `fputcsv`?

Comment: @ChenAsraf I edited the question. fputcsv I tried before, but made the same whitespaces and encoding conversion. So I tried it with the more elementar `fwrite` function.

Comment: Let's start with why are you using binary mode? Use only 'r+' or 'w' or 'w+' depending on your need, you don't need to use the binary flag 'b' because you're not putting binary information into the file.

Comment: It was a test to see whether the whitespaces disappear. So we can omit binary mode here.

Answer (score 0):

For that problem its easier to use `fputcsv`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php

Its made for such things.

```
<?php
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

example from php.net.

Comment: Used before. Screwed up the same.